# Java spring, tomcat 8.5.9. java.io.FileNotFoundException - Access Denied saving file on shared network directory

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, tomcat8, catalina

I have a problem that when running deployed on tomcat 8.5.9, I get access denied, and I can't create a file on a shared network folder. 
Running locally everything works perfectly.

I have tried **cmd** *dir \\10.65.161.93\c$\tscape\download* from the machine where it is deployed and I get all the files there, no problems. Probably there is some problem with tomcat, but I couldn't find the right answer. 
Machine is Windows Server 2012 R2.

> > java.io.FileNotFoundException: \10.65.161.93\c$\tscape\download\Test_test.txt (Access is denied) 
> >     java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> >     \10.65.161.93\c$\tscape\download\Test_test.txt (Access is denied)    at
> >     java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)   at
> >     java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)    at
> >     java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:237)
> >       at
> >     java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:187)...

```
 @Value("${export.machine}")
        private String exportMachine;

 @Value("${filename.lsps}")
        private String filenameLSPS;

 private void exportFile(String csv) {
            File file = new File(exportMachine+filenameLSPS);
            FileWriter writer;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(csv);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                log.error(ex.toString(), ex);
            }
        }
```

and yaml config:

```
filename.lsps=Test_test.txt
export.machine=\\\\10.65.161.93\\c$\\tscape\\download\\
```

Comment: 1) can you check which user is controlling the tomcat-server service? a local account or a domain account?
2) has this user access-right to the shared folder?

Comment: 1.) It says Local System. account. 2.) Need to check that, probably I can add users.

Comment: Figurate out, it is a tomcat service user access right problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: cheers, you may hit the button "this comment adds something useful to the post"